# Symfony2, Liipimaginebundle doesn't work and doesn't create folder and images

Tags: php, symfony, liipimaginebundle

I have just installed liipimaginebundle but it doesn't work and doesn't create folder and images

**app/config/routing.yml:**

```
_liip_imagine:
resource: "@LiipImagineBundle/Resources/config/routing.xml"
```

**app/config/config.yml:**

```
liip_imagine:
resolvers:
   default:
      web_path: ~

filter_sets:
    cache: ~
    travelThumb:
        quality: 80
        filters:
            thumbnail: { size: [120, 90], mode: inset }
```

**twig:**

```
<img src="{{ travel.image.webPath | imagine_filter('travelThumb') }}" alt="{{ travel.image.alt }}" />
```

when I inspect element in the browser I get this code:

```
<img src="http://localhost/agence/web/app_dev.php/media/cache/resolve/travelThumb/uploads/img/travels/1.jpeg" alt="entry_big_1.jpg">
```

and when I open that link inspect element in a new tab I get this error:

```
PHP exif extension is required to use the ExifMetadataReader
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This library requires PHP EXIF. You can compile PHP with --enable-exif. More information: 
http://php.net/manual/en/exif.installation.php